# How to present UIAlertController in Popover for iPhone with iOS 8

Tags: ios8, xcode6, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

I want to show a popover from navigation bar's title which is successfully configured as a button with multiple choices like Alert Controller on iPhone application. The following code is called when the title is tapped, but it shows action sheet on the bottom instead of popover. Can you help me find what's wrong? Thanks.

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: nil
                                                                          message: nil
                                                                   preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Close" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // dismiss viewcontroller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];
[alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // Handle Cancel
    // do nothing
}]];

alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
alertController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(250.0, 180.0);

UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverPresentation = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
popoverPresentation.sourceRect = self.parentViewController.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
popoverPresentation.sourceView = self.view;
popoverPresentation.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
popoverPresentation.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with code (programmatically) with `UIAlertController` as it has no popoverPresentationController on the iPhone. It is available only in iPad.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:PDFDataArray applicationActivities:nil];

if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)] ) { 
    NSLog(@"Popover available for this device type");
}
```

I've successfully presented popovers on the iPhone in the past, using adaptive segue style `Present As Popover` in interface-builder/storyboard and implementing `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` delegate method to return the correct `UIModalPresentationStyle`. You can also try this approach.